# Can I do something like this: $_REQUEST[$_REQUEST['field_name']]?

Tags: php

Can I do something like this?

```html
$captcha_results = $_REQUEST[$_REQUEST['field_name']];
```

I am interested in it, because I try to find out where I've made a mistake.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Yes you can. Will it give you the result that you are expecting? That I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. The one you've just asked is one of variable variables. You can learn more the PHP variables here:

1. [PHP Variable Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)
2. [Variable in Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

For example, you have `$var` containing value of `foobar`. You can use the value for other references (in my case, as an index of an array), as shown below.

```
$var = 'foobar';
$array['foobar'] = 'bar';

echo $array[$var];
```

This will output `bar` as a result.